# How can I select just one item of items to be show in a component after click? in vue js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I need to Click the icon to show in child component "comandasInd " the data of one item

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table :items="comandas">
    <template v-slot:items="props">
      <td>{{ props.item.nombre }}</td>
      <v-icon @click="abrirComanda(props.item)">
        book
      </v-icon>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
...
```

This is the component, but open all the compenents with all the items that i have, and i only need the one i clicked:

```
<comandasInd 
  v-for="comanda in comandas"
  :key= "comanda.cid"
  :nombre="comanda.nombre"    
  @click="abrirComanda(item)">
</comandasInd>                 

<script>
  export default {
    components: { comandasInd },    
    data: () => ({
      comandas: [],
      comanda: {
        nombre: '',
      }
      selectComanda: null,
   }),
   methods: {
     abrirComanda(comandas) {    
     this.selectComanda = comandas.nombre
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you need to render all the <comandasInd> ? Or just the selected?

Comment: just the selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (not sure if you need the @click here):

```
<comandasInd 
  v-if="selectComanda"
  :key= "selectComanda.cid"
  :nombre="selectComanda.nombre">
</comandasInd>                 

<script>
  export default {
    components: { comandasInd },    
    data: () => ({
      comandas: [],
      comanda: {
        nombre: '',
      }
      selectComanda: null,
   }),
   methods: {
     abrirComanda(comanda) {    
         this.selectComanda = comanda;
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: doesn´t, I need to click on the icon (item), and show only this data in the component. My code, show me all the items at the same time.